# Does there exist such a sequence $B$ when $p>5$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, prime-gaps

Let $A = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ be the sequence of odd primes are less than or equal to a prime number $p$.

Let $C$ be the infinite ascending sequence of composite numbers that their factors are all in $A$.

Let $B$ be a sequence of $n$ consecutive numbers of $C$ such that $b_n - b_{n-1} = a_2 - a_1, \ b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}  = a_3 - a_2, \ldots, \ b_2 - b_1 = a_n - a_{n-1}$.

For example, when $p=5,\ A=3,5, \ C= 9,15,25,27,45,75,81,..., \ B=25,27$.

> Does there exist such a sequence $B$ when $p>5$?

Edit: It seems the question above is not that easy to answer, here's alternative question:

> If there exist such a sequence $B$ when $p>5$, then $b_1$ must be greater than $3p$?

Comment: For each $k$, only one of these numbers can be divisible by $a_k$, so they must all be prime powers.

Comment: @joriki Why is it necessary that only one of the values if divisible by $a_k$? If $A=3,5,7,11$, then our sequence is $B=b,b+4,b+6,b+8$ out of which $3$ can divide both $b$ and $b+6$.

Comment: @Haran: You're right, I was overgeneralizing. For $n=3$ they all have to be prime powers, and for $n\gt3$ there are severe restrictions, e.g. for $n=4$ they all have to be prime powers except one could contain additional factors of $3$.

Comment: $n=3$ is impossible since it is known that the only solution to $a^m-b^n=2$ is $(a,b,m,n)=(3,5,3,2)$ where $m,n>1$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Also see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349304/does-there-exist-such-a-sequence-b-when-p5